# questions about file stream and buffer in C

Tags: c, stream, buffer

I'm reading "Advanced programming in the Unix Environment",in dection 5.5, P150, It says:

> 1.Any buffered output data is flushed before the file is closed. Any input data that may be buffered is discared....
>   2.When a process terminates normally, ... ,all standard I/O streams with unwritten buffered data are flushed ...

In 1, does it mean when I use fclose() to close a stream, the buffered input will be discared so that some data won't be written into file. If not, what's the meaning of "file is closed"?

In 2, does "unwritted buffered data are flushed" meah that buffered data will be writted into file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In #1, "buffered input" refers to data your program could read *from* the stream... so it's basically saying that once you close the stream you can't read more data from it.  The buffered input is data that may have been read from the file/device associated with the stream and placed in the stream's input buffer, but hasn't actually been read by *your* code yet (retrieved in advance and waiting for you to read it, basically).  Discarding it doesn't prevent anything from being written to the file because it's *input read from the file*, not output to be written *to* it.

In #2, they're saying that when your program ends (normally), anything your program has written to those streams that hasn't actually been written to the file on disk (or whatever device is associated with the stream) will be flushed, ie. actually written to the disk instead of sitting in the buffer.  Normally your stream writes are kept in buffers temporarily, and only actually written when the buffers are flushed (which may happen when the buffers are full, when `fflush()` is called, when the stream is closed, etc.)

Comment: In #1, "buffered input" is the data will be written into the file on disk, I think. According to what you say, output stream is data written into file, input stream is data read from file, right? Or, "buffered input" is different from input stream?

Comment: @tiantong "Buffered input" is data that has been read *from* the file on disk, into the stream's buffers.. but not necessarily consumed by your program until you call a function to read input like `fgets()`, `fread()`, etc.  "Input" and "output" are relative to your program, not the file.